# android:textSize=@dimen vs android:textSize="14sp"

Tags: android

```
android:textSize=@dimen vs android:textSize=“14sp”
```

which one is better as for as the efficiency or performance is concern
because what i believe for @dimen  it creates two references first to @dimen and next to 14sp.. and for direct 24sp only one reference is created.. 
So which one is better? if direct "14sp" then what's the use of giving @dimen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:textSize=@dimen
```

this better solution, dimensions as textSize is usually share in all your app, if you want to change (in this case) the size of the font, you only need to change one file. with `android:textSize=“14sp”` you have to search in all your layouts to make the change.

also you can create dimensions for every device depending of the size, dpi, ..... With `android:textSize=“14sp”` you can't do it in an easy way

Comment: You told about Maintenance of app. am asking about performance ans efficiancy as for as maintenance is concern it's correct

Comment: in efficiency maybe it's little slower android:textSize=@dimen, but it's something imperceptible. And I'm not sure but in runtime there is no difference, only in compilation time

Comment: Ya it's correct.. I got the clarification.. during run time it will directly create the hardCoded 14sp reference @dimend it's only for maintenance..

Answer (score 2):

> which one is better as for as the efficiency or performance is concern

They should be effectively equal. The overhead of loading the dimension resource should not be very large in the first place and will only occur once.

Answer (score 0):

A dimension value defined in XML. A dimension is specified with a number followed by a unit of measure. For example: 10px, 2in, 5sp. Because each resource is defined with its own XML element, you can name the file whatever you want and place different resource types in one file. However, for clarity, you might want to place unique resource types in different files.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_dimen">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```